# Crazy rounded rect UIBezierPath behavior on iOS 7. What is the deal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, cgcontext, uibezierpath

The simple UIView below draws a rounded rectangle. When I pass a corner radius of 65 or below it rounds correctly, but 66 and above and it generates a perfect circle! What is going on here? It should only show a circle when the corner radius is equal to 1/2 the frame width, but it seems that it is drawing a circle when the radius is about 1/3rd, no matter what the size of the view is. **This behavior appears on iOS 7. On iOS 6 I get expected behavior.**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface MyView : UIView
@end

@implementation MyView
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200) cornerRadius:65];
  CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextAddPath(c, path.CGPath);
  [[UIColor redColor] set];
  CGContextStrokePath(c);
}
@end

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  MyView *v = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
  [self.view addSubview:v];
}
@end
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Filed rdar://17801182

Comment: Good catch. Please keep this post updated.

Comment: This bug is still present on iOS 8.

Comment: Still present on iOS 9

Comment: Oh, here's a solution: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/code-for-ios-7-rounded-rectangles

Comment: Have been fighting with this all day. That's just super weird.

Comment: Still present on iOS 13.

Comment: Still present on… iOS 15. Wow.

Comment: Still present on... iOS 16. Wow again.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably never be fixed. Here is why.

The math to calculate if you can make a squircle is: `radius * magicMultiplier * 2`. If the result is longer than the side, it can't make a squircle so it makes a circle.

The `magicMultiplier` is required because to make it look like a squircle, the bezier curve needs to start from a longer distance than the radius. The magic multiplier provides that extra distance.

From my research and playing around with the bezier function, I believe the magic multiplier might be something around `1.0 + 8.0 / 15.0 = 1.533`.

So `66*(1+8/15)*2` is `202.4` which is longer than the shortest side (200), thus it makes it a circle.

However! `65*(1+8/15)*2` is `199.33` which is smaller than 200, so it squircles it correctly.

**Possible solutions**

1. Code your own bezier curve function (or get one online)
2. Use the view's layer.cornerRadius to achieve the same thing since Apple doesn't clamp the corner radius here.

```
layer.cornerCurve = .continuous
layer.cornerRadius = min(radius, min(bounds.width, bounds.height)/2.0)
// You might want to clamp it yourself
```

Bear in mind that `draw(in ctx)` doesn't work with `layer.maskedCorners`. So you can't use SnapshotTesting with those.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, to->circle bug happens at approx. 65%:

```
- "INFO --- width/height (SQUARE): 12.121212121212121"
- "INFO --- halfSize == maxRadius: 6.0606060606060606"
- "INFO --- cornerRadius: 3.967272727272727"
- "INFO --- ratioBug: 0.6546"

extension CGRect
{
    // For generic Rectangle
    // 28112022 (bug happens at 65%) (cornerRadius / maxRadius)
    // radiusFactor: [0, 1] 
    func getOptimalCornerRadius(radiusFactor: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
    {
        let minSize = self.sizeMin()
        let maxRadius = minSize / 2
        let cornerRadius = maxRadius * radiusFactor
        return cornerRadius
    }
}
```