# How to draw a rounded rectangle with UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I'm trying to mask a view with a rounded rectangle `UIBezierPath`. I want the mask to look **exactly** the same as if I were just setting `layer.cornerRadius`:

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80)
let cornerRadius = 30
```

**Using `cornerRadius`**:

```
let view = UIView(frame: frame)
view.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
```

**Using `UIBezierPath` mask**:

```
let view = UIView(frame: frame)
let maskingShape = CAShapeLayer()
maskingShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: frame, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
view.layer.mask = maskingShape
```

The resulting rounded rects are completely different. The standard cornerRadius works as expected while the bezier path just snaps to a full circle at a certain radius.

[image]

Apparently, this is intended behaviour from iOS 7.

**How then do I draw a standard rounded rectangle with a bezier path?**

I found [this category](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/code-for-ios-7-rounded-rectangles) but this has to be a joke right? Is there no simpler way? :(

**[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936003/crazy-rounded-rect-uibezierpath-behavior-on-ios-7-what-is-the-deal)**.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237863/how-to-control-an-uiviews-rounded-corners-separately-using-ibinspectable-in-sw/45245114#45245114 maybe can bring you some light about this

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to draw the bezier path myself. I'll give it a try though, thanks. Isn't it still super weird that `UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cornerRadius:)` simply does not do what you'd expect it to do?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Alright, so I tried your solution. The two rounded rects have different shapes (the one with layer cornerRadius and the one with the bezier path). I guess I'll just resort to using either of the two methods.